# Convergent series times a convergent sequence is a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

If $\sum a_n$ converges and if $\{b_n\}$ is monotonic and bounded, prove that $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

I have a proof that involves the using partial sums, but would like to know if there's any other way to get the job done, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Sigma a_n$ does not converge absolutely, you you cannot expect $\Sigma a_nb_n$ to converge absolutely. Therefore the usual comparison arguments (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) don't apply.

Hence I think the only way to prove this statement ist to use the Cauchy criterion (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series#Cauchy_convergence_criterion), which basically goes back to using partial sums.

Answer (score 0):

After further lecture notes, we were introduced to a theorem that says the following:

If conditions 1-3 are met for sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, then $\sum a_n b_n$ is convergent.

1. The partial sums of $\{a_n\}$ are bounded.
2. $\{b_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing.
3. As $n \to \infty$, $\{b_n\} \to 0$.

Condition 1 is met by the given: since $\sum a_n$ converges, the sequence of partial sums converges, and is therefore bounded.

Condition 2 will be covered in the subsequent construction.

Condition 3: Since $\{b_n\}$ is monotonic and bounded, it is convergent, say to $b$. If $\{b_n\}$ is monotonically increasing, let $\{c_n\}=b-b_n$. If $\{b_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing, let $\{c_n\}=b_n-b$. In either case, $\{c_n\}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence whose limit is $0$.

Therefore, by the theorem, $\sum a_nc_n$ is convergent.

$$\sum a_nc_n= \sum \pm a_n(b_n-b)=\pm \sum a_nb_n - a_nb$$

Since the leftmost piece of the equality is convergent, and $\sum a_nb$ is convergent by scalar multiple of a convergent series, $\sum a_nb_n$ must be convergent by algebra of convergent series.